# How to find the creation statement of table field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, the creation statement of query table is as follows: `show create table table01`.

Now I have a requirement. I want to query the creation statement of a field in this table. What SQL can I use to meet my requirement?

I used Google search for a long time without finding a satisfactory answer, and MySQL official website did not provide the SQL statement I wanted.

I hope a simple SQL statement can make me get the following :

```
ALTER TABLE `table01` 
ADD COLUMN `value` int(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'value'
```

---

Second edit

Thank you for your help. I'm from China. My English is not very fluent. I'm sorry that I don't express myself accurately in some places.

In fact, the reason why I have this requirement is that the project I am currently working on is agile development. The iteration speed between versions is very fast. Often because of the change of requirements, the database tables and fields will increase with it. But I am lazy, and I don't want to record the fields every time I add them. So I use java to make an automation program. At present, it can be compared quickly Quickly find out the differences between formal and test database tables and fields.

But I wonder if there is a better way to find out the creation statement of this field, so that my program looks more perfect.

[springboot-mysql-table-field-compare](https://github.com/kangyu06/springboot-mysql-table-field-compare)

Snowflakes fluttering north wind rustling(雪花飘飘北风萧萧)

Comment: You mean something like `SHOW CREATE COLUMN`? Edited: You can make custom `CREATE` query based on `information_schema.columns` as mentioned in P.Salmon comment below.

Comment: 'Now I have a requirement. I want to query the creation statement of a field in this table' - there isn't one. If you want the column definition you could query information_schema.columns or show columns https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are wanting to track the history of changes to your tables and columns, to know when things were added, and how? Otherwise I'm not sure what the purpose of your requirement is? Can you be clearer about _why_ you want this - maybe there is something we can suggest to help with your broader goal?

Comment: @kangyu . . . MySQL keeps track of the changes to the database -- not the code that was used to implement those changes, unless you have implemented an explicit logging mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. I've redacted the question

Comment: Ok thankyou for the clarification. The short answer is, there is no better tool in MySQL. The comparison tool you have built already is the standard way to do this job. Microsoft have produced similar tools for their SQL Server product, for example. The best you can do is a tool which compares the differences and then generates a SQL script which will apply those changes into the other database. And of course you should use source control to keep track of which scripts have been executed in each database.

Comment: Thank you. You're really enthusiastic

Comment: If you can, please give me a compliment, so that I can give you a compliment when I see a good answer. Thank you, I love stack overflow

Comment: I gave you an upvote to your question already. Good luck with your project.